# How can I get a object by getItemAtPosition in custom gridview?

Tags: android

I use the following code fill in a gridview control using ImageAdapter.

I hope to get a item of gridview, but  int i=((ViewHolder)imagegrid.getItemAtPosition(0)).imageview.getId() make the app crash, why?

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photo_main); 
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter();  
        GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);        
        imagegrid.setAdapter(imageAdapter);        
   }



    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ImageAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return count;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }        

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.photogalleryitem, null);
                holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
                holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.checkbox.setId(position);
            holder.imageview.setId(position);           
            holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
            holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
            holder.id = position;            

            return convertView;
        }


    }


    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageview;
        CheckBox checkbox;
        int id;
    }

}



<info.dodata.managephoto.PhotoRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/thumbImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-2dp"
        android:background="#70f2eada"
        android:text="" />

</info.dodata.managephoto.PhotoRelativeLayout>



package info.dodata.managephoto;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class PhotoRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    public PhotoRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public PhotoRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PhotoRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        setMeasuredDimension(getDefaultSize(0, widthMeasureSpec), getDefaultSize(0, heightMeasureSpec));

        int childWidthSize = getMeasuredWidth();
        int childHeightSize = getMeasuredHeight();

        heightMeasureSpec = widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childWidthSize, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where and why do you use such code ? post stacktrace. Why didn't you post the code where the call is made ?

Comment: I think the error is caused becase I don't implement public long getItemId(int position) in public class ImageAdapter , right?

Answer (score 0):

getItemAtPosition return a view, not your ViewHolder. You should have castException, don't you ?

Comment: And more, GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);  
          ImageView aa= (ImageView) ((View) imagegrid.getTag(0)).findViewById(R.id.thumbImage); don't work

Comment: I would set a onItemClickListener on the gridView, then, in the method onClick of the listener, you receive the view clicked as a parameter. You only have to do ((ViewFroup)view).findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);

Comment: Thanka. butI need to make all holder.checkbox as checked, so I need to get items by  getItemAtPosition

Comment: hum... This is difficult as BaseAdapter are recycling the views. So you could have one check box use for several item. You can't do that this way.

Answer (score 0):

implement on item click listeners

```
imagegrid .setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

   }});
```

Essentially the trick is to set and retrieve the position index via the `setTag` and `getTag` methods. The items variable refers to the data containing my custom (adapter) objects.

Comment: Thanks,but in my code I need to getItemAtPosition, how can I do  it?

Comment: Thanks! I needn't implement on item click listeners, I need to get an item in Gridview. could you tell me details about it

Comment: And more , GridView imagegrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.PhoneImageGrid);  
          ImageView aa= (ImageView) ((View) imagegrid.getTag(0)).findViewById(R.id.thumbImage); don't work

Comment: I need to make all holder.checkbox as checked, so I need to get items by  getItemAtPosition